# Hostpolicy.dll problems in Visual Studio 2022 and Net6

Tags: c#, exception, console, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I downloaded Visual studio 2022 final and Net6, but when I created a very beginning Console App, it builds ok, but when debugging it or without debugging it throw exceptions: says:

```
    A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\'.
    Failed to run as a self-contained app.
      - The application was run as a self-contained app because 'C:\Users\<UserName>\source\repos\ConsoleApp2022\ConsoleApp2022\bin\Debug\net6.0\ConsoleApp2022.runtimeconfig.json' was not found.

  - If this should be a framework-dependent app, add the 'C:\Users\<UserName>\source\repos\ConsoleApp2022\ConsoleApp2022\bin\Debug\net6.0\ConsoleApp2022.runtimeconfig.json' file and specify the appropriate framework.
```

please can any one provided me a guidance to solve this issue.

***note:*** I did a lot of search But I did not find any solution to mine, and the solutions were for previous net core

Comment: I do not know why there is no ansewer

Comment: I faced same issue

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue or work out what the issue was?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some command line options like:

```
--runtimeconfig .\ConsoleApp2022.runtimeconfig.json  
--depsfile .\ConsoleApp2022.deps.json
```